# Load balancer keeps EC2 instance out of service

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

When I set the ssl ciphers list in the EC2 instance to the below one,

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

the instance fails the health check from the application load balancer.

How can I find which ciphers in the cipher list on the server is supported/not supported by the load balancer? I have tried to enable the same set of ciphers in the server and on the load balancer's listener configuration also.

Also, when `HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5` is set on the server, the instance does not fail the health checks from the load balancer.